# How to set up multiple IP addresses on my Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I'm doing some computer network homework and I'm supposed to develop some sort of Peer to Peer file sharing software. I want to test it and run a few (five) instances on Ubuntu 11.10, which means each one needs to have a unique IP address.

I heard I can do that, but I don't know how.

How can I have more than one IP address on a single computer?

Comment: You may want to consider VMs for this, so that the packets are sent across some sort of real-*looking* network instead of just being routed around within the same OS instance.

Comment: So wait, do you have five different machines running Ubuntu? Or do you only have *one* machine? In the latter case, this is going to be difficult, and not practically possible. Consider setting up five virtual machines.

Comment: @slhck: No, it can be done easily enough. The real issue is if it can be considered an adequate test of the software.

Comment: VMs are best option. @slhck: this is Linux. Binding several IPs to one physical interface is doable and easy.

Comment: I have only one ubuntu

Comment: @m0skit0 Yeah, that's what I meant by "practical" though. In the case of building a P2P network, you'd want it to be a realistic scenario ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm. The easiest way to set additional ip addresses is just by

```
ip addr add 10.66.66.66/24 dev eth0
```

and the likes.

Then, your file sharing software should bind to those IP addresses. The question is - would they be routed out in such a way all of them would have access to the internet? or to each other? This can be a really fun exercise in iptables.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of IP addresses you can add to a device in this way? On my end I've been using the interfaces definitions with eth0:0, eth0:1, etc. which is limited to 254 IPs per NIC.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.1
ifconfig eth0:2 192.168.1.2
```

etc.

Answer (score -1):

In a local network you have multicast and you really do not need any sort P2P.
Maybe coordinating multicast well would help a lot (router will multiply packets, no extra file serving from clients)